# bootstrap 4 change navbar height causing navbar items to not be vertically centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a bootstrap 4 navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Toggle Button -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-target="#nav-content"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">THE VEGAN REPOSITORY</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home_page_footer">
                        <h5 class=" nav-item clickable white-text medium-text 
                                        right-text">
                                        ABOUT
                        </h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home_page_footer">
                        <h5 class=" nav-item clickable white-text medium-text 
                                        right-text">
                                        BLOG
                        </h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
                        <h5 class=" nav-item clickable white-text medium-text 
                                        right-text">
                                        LOGIN
                        </h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
                        <h5 id="    sign-in-button" class="nav-item clickable 
                                    medium-text right-text">
                            SIGN UP FREE
                        </h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

<!-- Toggle Button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content">
</button>



</nav>
```

I'd like to change the height of the navbar, but when I do, the links are no longer vertically centred.

70px

[image]

I have tried line-height, and flexbox options such as

```
nav {
   background-color: $brand-red;
   height:70px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

which does:

[image]

my only css used for the whole navbar is this:

```
nav {
  background-color: #fc4747;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; }
```

How do I vertically centre the navbar items if the navbar is 70px tall? The default height of a navbar is a bit smaller, around 50px.

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap styles are conflicting with your CSS. Without being able to reproduce the problem, however, we can only guess. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured I would address a few things here but first as to your question.  If you just want to change the height of the navbar instead of adding a specific height to the nav you could just add extra padding to the navbar to give you your desired height and then you wouldn't have to change a bunch of css throughout the rest of the navbar.  So doing this should give the navbar a height of 70px.

```
.navbar{padding:1rem}
```

Here is a fiddle of everything I address in this post in action [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/r6ae4jor/)

In this fiddle demo I have also added some responsive styles for stacking the navbar links at your collapse width.

Next If you are going to set a background color to the nav there is no reason to use the `bg-faded` class to the nav as this just gives you the background color for the nav so you can remove that class from your nav.

Then I see in your classes for your nav links you have a `white-text` class.  If you want white text for your navbar your can just use the class of `navbar-dark` and this will give you lighter text for the navbar instead of using `navbar-light`.  Just figured I would point that out.

Next In bootstrap 4 there is no `navbar-header` class so this is not necessary unless you are planning on custom styling something here.  And the `navbar-toggler` button is different in bootstrap 4 there are no `icon-bar` spans they just use the html code for this now `&#9776;`

Note: Addressing a huge pet peeve of mine you have h5 tags in your navbar.  Not sure why this is but I see people doing this a lot.  H tags are supposed to be used in order from h1 down to h6 and are supposed to be directly related to the page that you are on and not for the entire site.  If you have a good reason for this practice then by all means keep them there but I am not sure why I see people do this all of the time.  To me it is a bad practice just figured I would address this.

Comment: Thanks!! I actually did `$enable-flex: true;` in _custom.scss, so I need to work on the css a bit to make it work with that in mind, not using float. However that was not part of the question, so it is of course correct. Thanks for the extra tips.